# How to reconnect lost connections with EclipseLink?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I have the problem if the mySQL Server kills the session after 500 sec "sleeping-time", that the next request isn't successful. The same problem occurs after maybe 700 sec if the mySQL Server doesn't closes the sleeping connection.

What can I do?
Following the properties of my persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None" />
<property name="eclipselink.cache.alwaysRefresh.default" value="true" />
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.max" value="10" />
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" />
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.shared" value="true" />
```

And the transactiontype is RESOURCE_LOCAL if it's important to know.

Comment: Ok I now have a minus 1, but it would be also nice to understand what I did wrong in my question, because the question is realy important for me and I think you can read in the question, that it is defenetly not a problem of mySQL. For example the mySQL Workbench hasn't any problem if I kill the connection externely.

Comment: It's also possible that I disable the killing of the sleeping-connections, but like I said before the problem occurs after 700sec again.

Comment: your -1 is gone now - your question is completly valid. There seem to be people who think that connection pooling is trivial - but none of the following is answered properly: 
     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289075/how-to-modify-eclipselink-jpa-2-0-connection-retry-behavior
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220860/jpa-eclipselink-connection-timeouts/12222065#12222065
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718381/eclipselink-connection-timeout
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880365/diagnosing-an-eclipselink-connection-delay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How have you configured your connection pool?  If it a server datasource, the properties such as connection testing should be set in the server.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm#i1199711 for example settings.

If it is an EclipseLink pool, it should automatically attempt to retry queries when it detects a connection failure by default.  The properties controlling the behavior are only accessible through api in the DatabasePlaform class for your specific database, and can be set through a customizer as described here:
[How To modify Eclipselink JPA 2.0 connection retry behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289075/how-to-modify-eclipselink-jpa-2-0-connection-retry-behavior)

Comment: Thank you very much. The second one works for me. It turns out, that I had to manually set `login.setConnectionHealthValidationOnError(true); ` which I understand should be true by default.