# Automatically update database connection with EclipseLink

Tags: java, mysql, eclipselink

I currently have an application with the following database connection configuration:

```
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",     driver);
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",        url);
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user",       user);
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password",   password);
properties.put("eclipselink.cache.shared.default",  "false");
properties.put("eclipselink.query-results-cache",   "false");
properties.put("eclipselink.refresh",               "true");
```

However, due to the 8-hour timeout the MySql log file displays the following warning:

```
170509  9:40:10 [Warning] Aborted connection 692199 to db: 'databaseName' user: 'userName' host: 'host' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Has anyone ever encountered this same exception? I would like the connection to be automatically renewed by EclipseLink, with the intention of logging only warnings and errors that are really relevant.

Comment: Which application server do you use? You also can specify connection validation in JDBC connection pool settings of your application server.

Comment: In my case I have two applications, one web application that is running on Tomcat and the other is a service running on linux direct.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23546455/496099 which covers both use cases.

Comment: connection in server application I preffer via connection pool, and connection pool has dedicated parameters fro time-outs, aborted connection, closing management etc